# Gradient Colour Aspx

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I want to add gradient colors in my code I am new in this.

```
<script>
    function OnEndUpdate() {
        $("div:contains('Yahoo')")[32].style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

Comment: I don't know what you want with ``$("div:contains('Yahoo')[32]")" ``` but you can apply a gradient like this ```$(div).css({background:'linear-gradient(green,blue,green)'})```

Comment: Actually What u want plz clearify ur requirement ..but you can apply a different different gradient like this  ===>> $('#block').css({
    background: "-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ccc), to(#000))" 
});